# How to link Xml tags together

Tags: xml

Is it possible to link tags together. example: `<tag1>some data</tag1> <tag2>Here i want to link or copy tag1 data</tag2>` previously i dint write any xml to my application this is the first time i am using. pls guide me.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want the output to be? And in which language?

Comment: The output will show the data what i uploaded in tag1 the same should display in tag2. i want to link or merge two tags together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the xlink standard; see http://www.w3.org/TR/xlink/.  Its overkill but will accomplish what you want.

```
<doc xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <tag1 xml:id='tag1'>some data</tag1>
  <tag2 xlink:href='#tag1' />
</doc>
```

Comment: `'#tag1'` what this refers to. is this referring tag or xml:id.??

Comment: The href is a URI and only contains a fragment identifier.  So xlink will use the current document and yes the `#tag1` refers to `xml:id`.

Comment: Thank you. Again doubt whenever i parse Tag2 i will not get the data which i entered in Tag1. I am using java to parse the xml file. its getting null.